'thumbs up/down' button in streamlit st.button with st.chat_input making the screen blank after hitting the button
I had written below code to take the chat input and then provide response. But after hitting the 'Thumbs up' button, the screen does not even display 'Thanks for providing the feedback!' and resets immediately. Same behavior when 'Thumbs down' button too. Not sure why this is happening, is it a defect in streamlit.
st.write("Please provide feedback for the above content as correct, incorrect, or incomplete.")
user_question = st.chat_input("Enter the question here:")

if user_question:
    st.write("Your question is:", user_question)

    # Add thumbs up and thumbs down buttons
    col1, col2 = st.columns(2)

    with col1:
        if st.button(" Thumbs Up"):
            st.write("Thanks for providing the feedback!")

    with col2:
        if st.button(" Thumbs Down"):
            st.write("Thanks for providing the feedback. We will improve the content.")

Expectation : The display of 'st.write("Your question is:", user_question)' should stay in the screen and also display of either st.write("Thanks for providing the feedback!") or 'st.write("Thanks for providing the feedback. We will improve the content.")' should stay after hitting corresponding button.

The problem is that after you submit your question entered into the user_question field, the field itself gets cleared. So when you click any of the feedback buttons, the if user_question condition is not met anymore, as value of user_question is None. Hence why the whole section of your app, which depends on this condition, is not displayed.
To avoid this, you need to preserve the value of the most recent question. To do this, it's best to use st.session_state.
Here's a working code based on your example:
import streamlit as st

# Display the prompt for user feedback
st.write("Please provide feedback for the above content as correct, incorrect, or incomplete.")

# Capture user input
user_question = st.chat_input("Enter the question here:")

# Initialize session state if not already set
if "user_question" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.user_question = ""

# Update session state only if the input has changed
if user_question and user_question != st.session_state.user_question:
    st.session_state.user_question = user_question

# Display user input if available
if st.session_state.user_question:
    st.write("Your question is:", st.session_state.user_question)

    # Create two columns for feedback buttons
    col1, col2 = st.columns(2)

    with col1:
        if st.button(" Thumbs Up"):
            st.write("Thanks for providing the feedback!")

    with col2:
        if st.button(" Thumbs Down"):
            st.write("Thanks for providing the feedback. We will improve the content.")

